# JOOQ: update two tables with one2one relation

Tags: mysql, sql, jooq

I have 2 tables with 1:(0 or 1) relations
for example:

table1 - students

| id | last_name | first_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hart | John |

table2 - student_address

| id | student_id | address | is_married |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | something | true |

not every student has an address (for the example)

I want to update both tables, update students and if  exist relative row in student_address - update also the student_address.
is it possible to do it in one query in JOOQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can update multiple tables in a single statement using `JOIN`:

```sql
create table a (i int primary key, j int);
create table b (i int references a, k int);

insert into a values (1, 1);
insert into b values (1, 1);
update a join b using (i) set j = 2, k = 2;
select * from a join b using (i);
```

Resulting in

```
|i  |j  |k  |
|---|---|---|
|1  |2  |2  |
```

There's nothing special about that from a jOOQ perspective. Just translate it directly to jOOQ:

```java
ctx.update(A.join(B).using(A.I))
   .set(A.J, 2)
   .set(B.K, 2)
   .execute();
```